# What chess-opening does this cat play

Tags: chess, openings

I just saw this [funny cat video](http://www.viddler.com/explore/cheezburger/videos/1692/) where the cat gets beaten in chess by a trick opening. It is not the well known [fool's mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_mate), but I guess it is a famous opening too. Can anyone identify the opening that is played here?

Comment: The board appears to be mirrored.  The f-row is not to the right when playing black.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That appears to be the [Scholar's Mate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholar%27s_mate), the four-move game that ends with 4. Qxf7#.

> In chess, Scholar's Mate is the checkmate achieved by the moves 1. e4 e5 2. Qh5 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nf6? 4. Qxf7#. The moves might be played in a different order or in slight variation, but the basic idea is the same – the queen and bishop combine in a simple mating attack on f7 (or f2 if Black is performing the mate). Sometimes Scholar's Mate is referred to as the Four-Move Checkmate, though there are other ways to checkmate in four moves.

Obviously this is a fake video. I've never met a cat who would fall for this move.

Comment: +1: The result looks similar, I guess the cat just plays some strange moves that are even weaker than the moves in the classic Scholar's Mate. I'll accept the answer tomorrow if no one comes up with a better variation.

Comment: the cat is clearly not concentrating!